# Python re expression returning whole string, but groups not providing whole string

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to create a regular expression in python that will match certain elements of a user-inputted string.  So far, that is `re.match("( 0b[10]+| [0-9]+| '.+?'| \".+?\")+", user_cmd)`.

When `user_cmd = ' 12 0b110110 \' \' " " "str" \'str\''`, `re.match("( 0b[10]+| [0-9]+| '.+?'| \".+?\")+", user_cmd)` returns `<re.Match object; span=(0, 32), match=' 12 0b110110 \' \' " " "str" \'str\''>` which is the whole string so, because everything is matched, and everything in the regex is in parenthesis, everything should be in a group, right?  It turns out not because `re.match("( 0b[10]+| [0-9]+| '.+?'| \".+?\")+", user_cmd).groups()` returns `(" 'str'",)` (only one item).  Why is this?  How do I make the regular expression return each and every item it should return in the groups command?

Comment: Doesn't the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) say why? (*"If a group is contained in a part of the pattern that matched multiple times, the last match is returned."*) The last example there even is exactly like yours, just simpler.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to make each and every group match?

Comment: There is only one element of storage (specifically, one pair of start/end indexes) for each group number.  If a capture group is repeated, then each capture overwrites the indexes for the previous capture of the same group.  One solution would be to move to the new experimental `regex` module (instead of `re`): it stores all instances of a repeated capture, although I'm not familiar with the details.

Comment: @jasonharper Do you mean [this](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) or another? (I'm uncertain because that one looks neither "new" nor "experimental", what you say sounds like something we might get with `from __future__ import regex`.)

Comment: Please update your question with a few example strings you want to test, the regex you are using on those strings, what is returned, and what you would like to return. Right now I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is repeating a captured group, which will capture the value of the last  iteration in group 1 which is `'str'`

For your matches, you don't need to repeat a group if you want the separate matches, and you don't need a capture group if you want the matches only.

What you might do as all the parts start with a space is match a space and use a non capture group with the alternation `|`.

Instead of a non greedy quantifier `.+?` you can use a negated character class to have less backtracking.

```
 (?:0b[10]+|[0-9]+|'[^']+'|"[^"]+")
```

- `(?:` Match a space and start a non capture group for the alternation `|`

  - `0b[10]+` Match 0b and 1+ occurrences of `1` or `0`
  - `|` or
  - `[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits 0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `'[^']+'` Match from `'` till `'` using a negated character class which will match 1+ times any char except `'`
  - `|` Or
  - `"[^"]+"` Match from `"` till `"` using another negated character class
- `)` Close non capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8NnYZb/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/eWLNwh)

For example getting all the matches with re.findall to get all the matches:

```
import re
 
user_cmd = ' 12 0b110110 \' \' " " "str" \'str\''
pattern = r" (?:0b[10]+|[0-9]+|'[^']+'|\"[^\"]+\")"
 
print(re.findall(pattern, user_cmd))
```

Output

```
[' 12', ' 0b110110', " ' '", ' " "', ' "str"', " 'str'"]
```

---

If you want the full match, you can make use of the captures() using the [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module

```
import regex

pattern = r"""( (?:0b[10]+|[0-9]+|'[^']+'|\"[^\"]+\"))+"""
user_cmd = ' 12 0b110110 \' \' " " "str" \'str\''
m = regex.match(pattern, user_cmd)
print(m.captures(1))
```

Output

```
[' 12', ' 0b110110', " ' '", ' " "', ' "str"', " 'str'"]
```

[Python demo](https://tio.run/##NY3BCsIwEETv@YqwlyRUS6InBfFDklbaGmwPacN2Cwr995iAMgPDwO68@KFxmc8pTSEuSBz9y78Zix2Rx5nfOAKA5PJ@1b01uql2q4@XHMK2oqnE7sC2DprKgVJVvmXb6vExhGf@FdycuO6N0dnciWIoWgkhlxxOCBYKpnDr0NEwyh/8wP9TikWcZpKhHrpIG/pVGqVS@gI)

Comment: Can you tell what backtracking that reduces?

Comment: This has the same issue that I had mentioned under the other answer, for example for `user_cmd = ' 12 stop 34'` it matches the `34` which the original doesn't.

Comment: @Manuel If you use a non greedy quantifier, the engine has to give up matches until it can match the next part. Using a negated character class, there is a linear match. See https://regex101.com/r/xY5gin/1 vs https://regex101.com/r/QBJikS/1

Comment: Those pages contain a lot of information, where shall I look?

Comment: @Manuel You can look at the number of steps. Also note that for the string `user_cmd = ' 12 stop 34` This is the result with the pattern from OP https://ideone.com/K243M2 and this is result with my pattern https://ideone.com/zLVs91 which is exactly the same result.

Comment: You're using the OP's pattern there, but with the wrong method (`findall` instead of `match`).

Comment: @Manuel Yes re.match starts from the start of the string, but all the parts of the string are represented in the string and there are no gaps between the matches.

Comment: Does that site show how it counted those numbers of steps? And how does that relate to backtracking? I'd understand there'd be backtracking(?) with a regex like `a.*?b` and a string like `aaaaaaaaaa`, as the engine would at each position see an `a` and go hunting unsuccessfully for a `b`. But since the regex is like `a.*?a`, i.e., same "start" and "end" character, I don't see how it would backtrack where `a[^a]*a` wouldn't.

Comment: @Manuel Please read this http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#basics and this http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast page

Comment: @Manuel And yes, if you select pcre (which is not Python) you can see how the backtracking works https://regex101.com/r/f1vz1d/1/debugger

Comment: @Manuel I have added another example with regex.match and the capture group collection.

Comment: *"there are no gaps between the matches"* - There is one. Between your matches `' 12'` and `' 34'`, there's the gap `' stop'`. The OP's original on the other hand [only matches the `' 12'`](https://ideone.com/1UQMev). The `' stop'` makes it stop.

Comment: @Manuel In that case the regex with the PyPi module will only match ' 12'

Comment: Ok I think I see now what backtracking you mean, what you mean with linear match, and why you said *less* backtracking. I find the step counts misleading, for example `'                        '` matches `'[^']+'` in just [four steps](https://regex101.com/r/3roodb/1), regardless of how long I make the string. The PyPi solution looks good, yes.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, I propose to use *findall* method.

```py
user_cmd = ' 12 0b110110 \' \' " " "str" \'str\''
matchs = re.findall(r" 0b[10]+| [0-9]+| '.+?'| \".+?\"+", user_cmd)

print(matchs)
```

my result :

```
[' 12', ' 0b110110', " ' '", ' " "', ' "str"', " 'str'"]
```

I hope it's help you :)

Comment: That's not equivalent, though, as your matches aren't necessarily consecutive.

Comment: And the trailing `+` shouldn't be there.